# ANGULAR (Version 17): Can't bind to 'ngMode' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, forms, import, angular17

I am trying to create a form in the newest version of angular (17.0.7)

For my backend I'm using Express and for my database I'm using MongoDb. I believe I have this setup okay, and I have no errors.

I ran into trouble when I tried to setup my service and the ts where the form lives.

In the last Angular version there was an app.modules file where I would put the injections needed to address the error in my title. In this Angular version there is no app module, and from my understanding, the injection just happens on the standalone component's ts, but when I do this I get this error:

ERROR Error [NullInjectorError]: R3InjectorError(Standalone[e])[e -> e -> e -> e]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for e!

Can someone advise me on what I'm setting up here incorrectly please?

**component.html:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Create Pokemon Component</h1>
    <form (ngSubmit) = "submitPokemonForm()">

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="nameOfPokemon" class="form-label">Name of Pokemon:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pokemon Name" name="pokemonName" [ngModel]="submittedPokemon.pokemonName">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Upload Photo of Pokemon:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile" name="pokemonImage" [ngModel]="submittedPokemon.pokemonImage">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Pokemon</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from '../shared-service.service' //added this
import{FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms'; //added this manually in order to use forms
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http' //added this manually because it provides functionality to perform HTTP requests and manipulate said requests and their responses

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-pokemon',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, HttpClientModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  templateUrl: './create-pokemon.component.html',
  styleUrl: './create-pokemon.component.css'
})
export class CreatePokemonComponent {

  submittedPokemon = {
    pokemonName: "",
    pokemonImage: ""
  }

  sendingPokemonObservable = {};
  hasPokemonFormErrors = false; //Default state of the form errors
  pokemonFormErrors : any; //Where the errors willl be stored
  hasSubmittedSuccessfully = false;
  successMessage : any;


  constructor( private _httpService: SharedService ) {
  }

  submitPokemonForm() {
          // console.log("This console log is from the submittedPokemonForm function in the create Pokemon component.");
      // console.log("This is the value of the date submitted via the form before the service:", this.submittedPokemon)
      this.sendingPokemonObservable = this._httpService.pokemonService(this.submittedPokemon).subscribe(pokemonData => {
        // console.log("This is the from data submitted via the form after being subscribed to:", pokemonData)
        // @ts-ignore .ts is not happy with 'pokemonData.errors', so I used an ignore here
        if(pokemonData.errors) { //The name 'errors' is the label of the mongoose object containing all the model validation errors
          // console.log("This console log means there are errors when the Pokemon form atempted to submit, so it was unsucessful.")
          this.hasPokemonFormErrors = true;
          this.pokemonFormErrors = pokemonData;
          // console.log("Here are the form errors:", this.pokemonFormErrors.errors);
          // console.log("Here is a specific error:", this.pokemonFormErrors.errors.firstName.message) 
        }
        else {
          // console.log("This console log means the pokemon form submitted succesfully.");
          this.hasSubmittedSuccessfully = true;
          this.successMessage = "Pokemon created successfully!"
          this.hasPokemonFormErrors = false;
        }
      })
  }


}
```

**service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SharedService {
  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  pokemonService(submittedPokemon: any) {
    console.log("This console log is from the shared.service.ts. It is specifically from the pokemonService function which is making the request to the backend");
    console.log("This is all the data that was submitted from the form:", submittedPokemon);
    return this._httpClient.post(import.meta.env["NG_APP_BACKEND_URL"] + '/submitPokemon', submittedPokemon) //works but need to get mongoose errors
  }

  // testService() {
  //   console.log("This is a console log from the test service function in the shared service file");
  //   return this._httpClient.get('/');
  // }
}
```

Comment: please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated, the code seems fine, problem might be elsewhere!

Comment: You might try [(ngModel)] instead of [ngModel]. That would bind two-ways instead of one.